# Using windows path style in GIT bash

Tags: git

I run git in windows and have project in path `c:\projects`

I know I can reach this folder in GIT bash by command:

```
cd /c/projects/
```

Is it possible somehow make GIT understand Windows path style in order to have possibility run command:

```
cd "c:\projects\"
```

Comment: Not that I know of.  Your current solution of placing the entire Windows style path in double quotes is how I would do it.

Comment: Switch to git CMD?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen You mean that by placing windows style path in double quotes should work? Command `cd "c:\projects\"` not works in my case

Comment: Hmmm...maybe it won't work with Windows commands, but it should work with Git commands.

Comment: Sorry, it works. This is what I was looking for. It is sad that thee is no directory autocomplete function after pressing TAB

Answer (score 1):

Windows paths are recognized by all git bash programs, since they are running on top of the windows. What is happening is that the backslashes are being interpreted by git bash. Just escape them along with any white spaces and you're good to go:

```
cd C:\\progects\\
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just surround the windows path in Git Bash now (since at least `git version 2.26.2.windows.1`)

```
cd "c:\projects\"
```

The opposite is also true. You can generally use a posix/unix/linux style path in Windows `cmd`. If it's an absolute path, you just need to replace the drive letter `/c` with `c:`

```
cd "path/to/file"
cd "c:/path/to/file"
```